# Proper way to attach class to user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, tinymce, vue.js

I have a WYSIWYG editor (Tinymce) where I allow users to post a youtube video.

To make a video content responsive I want to attach class "video-container" around
"iframe" tags that's inserted when users paste a youtube link through the editor, otherwise the video gets out of the editor container.

The only thing I have come up with is to use "setInterval" and find if the iframe tag has inserted and its parent has the "video-container" class, otherwise attach it.

Is this a good way to go?I want to know if there is a better way or can I do this with simple css??

By the way, I am using Vuejs and Jquery here.When the document is ready I execute this function

```
setInterval(function() {
   //this.$els.body is just to access the editor content

    var target = this.$els.body.querySelectorAll('iframe:not(#article-body_ifr)')
    for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        if(! $(target[i]).parents().hasClass('video-container')) {
            $(target[i]).wrap("<div class='video-container'></div>")
        }
    }
  }.bind(this), 6000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tniyMCE onChange instead http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onChange

```
// Adds an observer to the onChange event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
          ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
                  console.debug('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + l.content);
          });
   }
});
```